# Explicit Euler Method's Order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am seeing everywhere that the order of the Explicit
Euler Method is 2 but I can't prove it on my own. The textbook that I found the method says that the proof is very easy so it is up to the reader to find it but I can't! I began it for fun but it doesn't seem to be. Can someone prove it?

$$y_{n+1}=y_{n}+\frac{1}{2}h[f(x_{n},y_{n})+f(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})]$$

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote down is the implicit trapezium method. As you have explicit and Euler in the title, one could guess that you mean the improved Euler or [Heun's 2nd order method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heun's_method). In that case let us look at the local error.

Let $y(x)$ be an exact solution of the autonomous equation $y'=f(y)$, $y(t_0)=y_0$ (you can make any ODE autonomous by adding the time as an additional component). Then 
$$
y''=f'(y)y'=f'(y)f(y), \\
y'''=f''(y)[f(y),f(y)]+f'(y)^2f(y)\\~\\
\implies y(t+h)=y+hf(y)+\frac{h^2}2f'(y)f(y)+\frac{h^3}6\left(f''(y)[f(y),f(y)]+f'(y)^2f(y)\right)+O(h^4)
$$
 and the Taylor expansion on the right uses
$$
f(y+hf(y))=f(y)+hf'(y)f(y)+\frac{h^2}2f''(y)[f(y), f(y)]+O(h^3)
$$ 
so that
\begin{align}
y_1&=y_0+\frac h2 (f(y_0)+f(y_0+hf(y_0))\\
&=y_0+hf(y_0)+\frac{h^2}2f'(y_0)f(y_0)+\frac{h^2}4f''(y_0)[f(y_0), f(y_0)]+O(h^4)
\end{align}
This gives equality up to the terms quadratic in $h$ if $y_0=y(t)$. Thus the local discretization error is $O(h^3)$ and then the global error $O(h^2)$, as, in a first approximation, the summation of $N=T/h$ errors of size $h^3$ results in a total of magnitude $N·h^3=T·h^2$.